# Import key material that is 64 bytes in size into a HMAC_SHA_256 KMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I've been given a 64 byte secret to be used with HMAC_SHA_256. I can readily use this secret to generate a hash in Java as per below

```
SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(secret, "HmacSHA256");
Mac sha256 = (Mac) Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256").clone();
sha256.init(keyspec);
sha256.doFinal(prehash.getBytes())
```

I would like to outsource this logic to KMS, and import this 64 byte Key Material into KMS. However I get the InvalidCiphertextException error. Based on my research, it appears KMS only supports a 32 Byte key for HMAC_SHA_256.

However, the spec (and example Java code implementing the spec) supports arbitrary key sizes, it will simply sha256 anything larger than the block size of 64 bytes.

I want to understand why this restriction exists in KMS, unless I've missed something

For brevity, attempting to run the following aws kms commands

```
aws kms get-parameters-for-import \
    --key-id XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX \
    --wrapping-algorithm RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256 \
    --wrapping-key-spec RSA_4096 > import.json

cat import.json | jq -r .PublicKey | openssl enc -d -base64 -A -out WrappingPublicKey.bin
cat import.json | jq -r .ImportToken | openssl enc -d -base64 -A -out ImportToken.bin

openssl rand -out PlaintextKeyMaterial.bin 64 #Note that 32 works, 64 does not

openssl pkeyutl \
    -encrypt \
    -in PlaintextKeyMaterial.bin \
    -out EncryptedKeyMaterial.bin \
    -inkey WrappingPublicKey.bin \
    -keyform DER \
    -pubin \
    -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep \
    -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha256 \
    -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha256


aws kms import-key-material --key-id XXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX \
    --encrypted-key-material fileb://EncryptedKeyMaterial.bin \
    --import-token fileb://ImportToken.bin \
    --expiration-model KEY_MATERIAL_DOES_NOT_EXPIRE
```

Comment: You'll get better (or any) answers if you show your KMS code.

Comment: It's AWS KMS, it's an online portal or cli, not sure how much it would help. I've included nonetheless

Comment: It's a series of steps, using multiple tools. By showing the actual steps that you took, rather than just saying "I can't do this" you let someone who's familiar with the process (not me) to point out where you may have missed something.